# Caused by : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils

Tags: java, apache-camel, axis, apache-servicemix

I am new in Apache Camel and SOAP Jira Client, so I generated some Classes using axis wsdl2java and I deployed the bundle in servicemix. For ServiceMix, Axis doesn't mean anything that why I add a Third part dependency and I generated a plugin that contains All the Jars that I need. 
Here is the list of Jars: 
-Axis 1.4 
-Axis saaj 1.4 
-Axis wsdl4j 1.5.1 
-commons-discovery 
-commons-logging 
-javax.xml.parsers 1.1 
-javaxp api 1.4.2 
-javaxrpc 1.1 
-jndi 1.2.1 
-w3c dom 
-wmlParserApi 2.0.2 
When the Bundle Started I got this Error.

`Caused by:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils
        at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179) 
        at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)[674:TestTest3:1.0.0] 
        at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)[674:TestTest3:1.0.0] 
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.<init>(AxisClient.java:52)[674:TestTest3:1.0.0] 
        at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)[674:TestTest3:1.0.0] 
        at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)[674:TestTest3:1.0.0] 
        at com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.client.test.JiraSoapServiceServiceLocator.<init>(JiraSoapServiceServiceLocator.java:16)[669:JiraSoapClientCamelBlueprint.JiraSoapClientCamelBlueprint:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]`

When I checked The axis Jar I found this Class.

Can any one help me please !!

Answer (score 0):

As the exception name suggests, the class is not visible to the process running the axis.